# Is it possible to run a 4 dimensional work item in pyopencl?

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I have a `pyopencl` based code which runs perfectly fine for 3-dimensional work groups, but when moving to 4-dimensional work groups, it breaks down with the error:

`pyopencl._cl.LogicError: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel failed: INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION`

Digging around, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34310203) to another question, which implies that `OpenCl` in fact allows higher dimensional work groups.

So my question is if it is possible to change this setting in `pyopencl`. From this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13010675/6029810) elsewhere, I understand that `pyopencl` immediately inputs the dimensions, but given the error I have, I think there must be some issue.

This is a minimal sample code to replicate this error.
The code works well for the first kernel function, it breaks down on the second one.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

context = cl.create_some_context() 
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)  


kernel_code = """
__kernel void fun3d( __global double *output)
{
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    size_t j = get_global_id(1);
    size_t k = get_global_id(2);
    size_t I = get_global_size(0);
    size_t J = get_global_size(1);
    #
    size_t idx = k*J*I + j*I + i;
    # 
    output[idx] = idx;
}

__kernel void fun4d( __global double *output)
{
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    size_t j = get_global_id(1);
    size_t k = get_global_id(2);
    size_t l = get_global_id(3);
    size_t I = get_global_size(0);
    size_t J = get_global_size(1);
    size_t K = get_global_size(2);
    #
    size_t idx = l*K*J*I + k*J*I + j*I + i;
    # 
    output[idx] = idx;
}
"""

program = cl.Program(context, kernel_code).build()

I = 2
J = 3
K = 4
L = 5

output3d = np.zeros((I*J*K)).astype(np.float64)
cl_output3d = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, output3d.nbytes)

program.fun3d(queue, (I,J,K), None, cl_output3d)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, output3d, cl_output3d)
queue.finish()


import code; code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))
# 4d attempt

output4d = np.zeros((I*J*K*L)).astype(np.float64)
cl_output4d = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, output4d.nbytes)

program.fun4d(queue, (I,J,K,L), None, cl_output4d)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, output4d, cl_output4d)
queue.finish()
```

Comment: Just query what's the max number of dimensions your implementation supports, for example: `clinfo | grep dim`. But I never heard of more than 3.

Comment: Ah, I see, `clinfo | grep dim` tells me that "Max work item dimensions 3 " for my two devices; I think this settles it. 

If you wish to, please post your comment as an answer, to close this question.

Comment: Answer added. Accept if you are happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to specify more dimensions than supported by implementation is not going to work.

The maximum number of supported dimensions can be queried via `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS` or in terminal, for example:

```
$ clinfo | grep dim
Max work item dimensions 3
```